# Unable to bootstrap commerce engine

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-server

We are trying to setup Sitecore commerce 8.2.1 update 2.
The database is on a remote server.

The windows login is with a user `SitecoreServices`who is an administrator.
The same user is also added to SQL Server.

When running the setup for CommerceServer.exe, the option selected is `Windows Authentication` and on clicking 'Test`, it says - successfully connected to database.

The Commerce Server installation went fine.

When trying to run the bootstrap by this URL -

`http://habitat.commerceengine.dev.local:5000/commerceops/Bootstrap()`

there are a no. of error logs in the page and all of them show the same reason:

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and   
cannot be used with Windows authentication
```

For the database server also, I have created the `SitecoreServices` login with administrator privileges

> {
>         "MessageDate":"2018-06-13T12:56:34.4378692Z","Code":"Error","Text":"SQL:block:findentity.Exception:
>   SQL.GetEntityCommand.Exception:
>   Id=Entity-CommerceEnvironment-CommerceOps|Environment=GlobalEnvironment|Message='Login
>   failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
>   Windows
>   authentication.'|Number=18452|Procedure=''|Line=65536","CommerceTermKey":"SQL:block:findentity"
>       }

Comment: How your connection string to SQL server looks like in Sitecore Commerce engine json?

Comment: Check the app pool user identity of commerce engine instance where bootstrap is done. And see if it’s the same user as the one setup with permissions in sql

Answer (score 1):

If your database is on a remote server and you are not using a Domain/Active Directory user, you need to setup your Commerce Engine to use SQL Authentication instead. You can change that by going to CommerceEngine\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json, under EntityStoreSqlPolicy set TrustedConnection to false, supply the SQL user username and password.

Comment: After adding in all the 4 global.json files also, this error is not resolved. Do I have to change it in any other config file ? @rameez

Comment: This did not help

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while trying to install Sitecore Commerce 9.2 in local machine.

1. add IP address and system name to host file.
2. add the account/username to “Access this computer from the network” local security policy (secpol.msc)
   Then it got resolved.

For more details check here https://sitecore-commerce.blogspot.com/2020/10/login-failed-login-is-from-untrusted.html